# Shiny plot not updating when inputs are changed

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, reactive

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)

movies = read.csv("/Users/michael/Desktop/stat 479 proj data/marvel_clean.csv")
reviews = read.csv("/Users/michael/Desktop/stat 479 proj data/marvel_reviews_clean.csv")

reviews = reviews %>% slice(-(2:4)) %>% rename(Title = Film)

J.dat = left_join(movies,reviews, by = "Title")

J.dat = J.dat %>% mutate(date = substr(ReleaseDateUS, 1, 4)) %>% select(-ReleaseDateUS)
J.dat$date = as.numeric(J.dat$date)
J.dat = J.dat  %>% 
  mutate_all(~replace(., is.na(.), 0))  %>%
  select(-CinemaScore, -CinemaScore.1)

Distributor <- pull(J.dat, Distributor) %>%
  unique() %>%
  na.omit()



barplot <- function(df) {
  ggplot(df, aes(x=Title, y=Budget, fill=Budget, col = Distributor)) +
    geom_bar(width = 0.75,  stat = "identity", colour = "red", size = selected, alpha = selected) +
coord_flip()
}
    


### definition of app
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Marvel Movies"),
  selectInput("Distributor", "Studio", Distributor, multiple = TRUE),
  sliderInput("year", "Year", min = min(J.dat$date), max = max(J.dat$date), c(1986, 2021)),
  sliderInput("rating", "Rating", min = min(J.dat$Metacritic), max = max(J.dat$Metacritic), c(0, 88), sep = ""),
  plotOutput("Marvel_Bar")
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  movies_subset <- reactive({
   J.dat %>%
      mutate(selected = (
       (Distributor %in% input$studio) 
        (Metacritic >= input$rating[1]) &
        (Metacritic <= input$rating[2]) &
      (date >= input$year[1]) &
         (date <= input$year[2]) 
      ))
  })
  
  output$Marvel_Bar <- renderPlot({
    barplot(movies_subset())
  })
}

app <- shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am running into an issue where my plot is not updating when any of my inputs are changed.  I think the issue may lie some where in my reactive function but I have not been able to figure it out (still very new to shiny).  The shiny app runs it just wont update.

The data I am using can be downloaded here:
https://www.kaggle.com/minisam/marvel-movie-dataset?select=marvel.csv

Comment: A couple of thoughts: (1) `barplot(data.frame(..))` doesn't work, its first argument needs to be a vector or matrix of heights; (2) your reactive block doesn't filter any rows or make changes to column-values, it merely adds/replaces a single column named `selected`. Perhaps you're intending to filter on that column?

Comment: you are passing `movies_subset()` to the barplot function, but not using it. you only use `J.dat`

Comment: @langtang I changed somethings based on your comment and i fixed that problem(updated the code in the barplot function) but now i am getting this error message where the plot should appear: Problem while computing `selected = (...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  movies_subset <- reactive({
   J.dat %>% filter(
      (Distributor %in% input$studio) &
      (Metacritic >= input$rating[1]) &
      (Metacritic <= input$rating[2]) &
      (date >= input$year[1]) &
      (date <= input$year[2]) 
      )
  })
```

server function needed to be changed to this and it now works